# how to load css rules using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I am currently working with Vert.x. I can easily load the js files needed but when it comes to CSS, nothing loads EVER. So i guess my last resort is to write up some js to set these css rules(super last resort is to write the css INSIDE the html file).

Is there a nice way to do this?
I was thinking something like:

```
function loadIndexCss()
{
    document.getElementById("p2").style.color="blue";
    document.getElementById("p2").style.fontFamily="Arial";
    document.getElementById("p2").style.fontSize="larger";
}
```

save that in a file, then:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../css/css.js"></script>

<body onload="loadIndexCss()">
    <form id='frm_login'>
        <fieldset >
            <legend>Admin Login</legend>
            <label for='u' >Username: </label>
            <input type='text' name='username' id='u' maxlength="25" class="blocky"/>
            <label for='p' >Password:  </label>
            <input type='password' name='password' id='p' maxlength="25" class="blocky"/>
            <br/>
            <input type='button' name='Login' value='Login' id="btn_login" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
```

will that even work? if this is stupid, please teach :)

Comment: _but when it comes to CSS, nothing loads EVER. So i guess my last resort is to write up some js_ - What about fixing the CSS instead?!

Comment: @Andreas what do you mean fix the css? the syntax is correct etc, and it's not even a lot, all there is is this ".blocky{display:block}" and maybe 5-6 of these one liners. i was hoping to use bootstrap by twitter but vertx is bad with css for some reason.

Comment: @yaojiang: He means: Find out why you're not getting the CSS served up, and fix that. Tim's pretty responsive on [the Vert.x group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/vertx). It's going to be a simple thing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that would be my next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should work. You can also do it the dirty way, creating named style tag:

```
<style id="sty"></style>
```

and then add the CSS:

```
 document.getElementById("sty").innerHTML = "a {color: blue}";
```

Comment: thats interesting. ive tested what i have just now and it works, maybe theres a cleaner way.

Comment: Well, it is interesting, how smart browsers are today. However, if you want cleaner way, figure out why your CSS file doesn't load.

Comment: @yaojiang: *"maybe theres a cleaner way"* There's no "maybe" about it.